# Properties of ordered pairs that satisfy $x^2 +y^2 =a$

Tags: square-numbers, sums-of-squares

I want to know number of ordered pairs $(x,y)$ satisfying $x^2 +y^2 =a$.

Let $n(a)$ be the number of ordered pairs $(x,y)$ satisfying $x^2 +y^2 =a$.

If $x^2 +y^2 =a$ and $z^2 +w^2 =b$, then $(xz+yw)^2 +(xw-yz)^2 =ab$. 
 So, I guess that if $a,b$ is coprime, $n(ab)=n(a)n(b)$.

 To prove it, I need to prove if $x^2 +y^2 =a$ and $z^2 +w^2 =ab$, then $\frac{xz+yw}{a}$ is integer.

 How can I prove it?

edit: It can't hold...

Comment: The [sum of squares function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_squares_function) is well documented online.  Note that you really need to clarify the nature of $a,b$  (usually they are taken to be integers but I guess you meant to require them to be non-negative?).  In any case, try some examples.  What is $n(2)$?  What is $n(3)$?  What is $n(6)$?

Answer (score 1):

The number $n(a)$ is equal to zero for all $a$ tabulated
at [OEIS A022544](https://oeis.org/A022544). So we have no solutions for
$$
a=3,6,7,11,12,14,15,19,21,22,23,\cdots
$$
In fact, a positive integer $a$ is the sum of two
squares if and only if each prime factor $p$ of $a$ such that $p \equiv 3 \bmod 4$ occurs to
an even power in the prime factorization of $a$.
Also for such integers, the number $n(a)$ can be computed. In general we have the formula
$$
n(a)=r_2(a)=4(d_1(a)-d_3(n)),
$$
where $d_j(a):=\sum_{d\mid c,d\equiv j(4)}1$.

Comment: how to prove the formula? I see in wikipedia but there is no proof.

Comment: The proof is classical and in any book on number theory. I like the proof in  Tom Apostol's book. More references are given [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SumofSquaresFunction.html).

Comment: But I have only burton's elementry number theory.... have you the link containing proof?

Comment: Sure, just google it, I become hundreds of answers. For example, [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiMhoKQvIPyAhXspYsKHfpbAbwQFjABegQIBBAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Bjsessionid%3D83525AC8739D64BB0D60C09FA23DFDF6%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.307.522%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&usg=AOvVaw3LM-8wr-ZqHSFX7pvMwlX2), Theorem $1$.